# How do I split my text file into an 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, file

This is my code so far

```
string filename = @"marks.txt";
try
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
    using (reader)
    {
        int lineNum = 0;
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            lineNum++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", line);
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Can not find the file {0}", filename);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid directory in file path.");
}
catch (IOException)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Can not open the file {0}", filename);
}
```

What I want to make it so it reads the file which has a bunch of marks and names in it and split them into 2 separate arrays so I can print out who got the highest and lowest mark, the average mark and also put everyone who got over a certain mark like 80 and write a new file for them.

edit:
The File Roughly looks like this for about 20 lines:

```
50 Adam
23 Jennifer
85 Sanjay
```

Comment: you could help people by being more specific about "a bunch of marks and names".

Comment: to be able to help you, we need to see the content of the file. at least a part of it. or at least a viable description of it. Is there a pattern? and if so what is the pattern? is a separator used for the lines? or even for the elements within a line? all these question you need also to ask yourself to be able to solve it

Comment: if you intend afterwards to sort and filter the resulting collection I would suggest for you to create a custom class with properties for the information (name, mark) from the file. each instance/object of this class can then (after splitting) represent 1 data point of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt");

var scores =
    lines
        .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2))
        .Select(x => new { name = x[1], score = int.Parse(x[0]) })
        .ToArray();

string highest = scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.score).Select(x => x.name).First();
string lowest = scores.OrderBy(x => x.score).Select(x => x.name).First();
double average = scores.Select(x => x.score).Average();

var over80 = scores.Where(x => x.score > 80).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"output.txt", over80.Select(x => $"{x.score} {x.name}"));
```

Now, in case you have two or more people with the highest or the lowest score, then you need this:

```
string highest = String.Join(", ", scores.ToLookup(x => x.score, x => x.name)[scores.Max(x => x.score)]);
string lowest = String.Join(", ", scores.ToLookup(x => x.score, x => x.name)[scores.Min(x => x.score)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your file has marks and names like this:

```
John Doe, 89
David Smith, 74
Ramkumar Sundararajan, 85
```

In your code where you read lines, you can split the tokens like this:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
var tokens = line.Split(',');
string name = tokens[0];
int marks = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
```

You will need to handle errors if the input is not in the right format.

Once you have the name and the marks, you can store them in a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) or in two different arrays and operate on the values.

Comment: Would this also work if in the file the marks were first and there was a space between them and the names?

Comment: @YeetLord05 - It would be better if you added a sample of your file to the question.

Comment: @YeetLord05, you can modify the above code to what you want.  If you want to split by space, change: Split(' ').  If you want the marks to be first, then change: marks = int.Parse(tokens[0]).  Note that if you have spaces in your names, then you would need to use a different strategy.